# Getting System.NotSupportedException while mocking FirstOrDefaultAsync method in C# NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to write Unit Tests for the method below:

```
  public async Task<int> Method1(string agentId, long userId)
    {
        using var scope = _provider.CreateScope();
        var class1Object = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Class1>();
        var user = await class1Object.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.UserId == userId && a.AgencyId == agencyId);
        if (user == null) return 0;
        user.IsActive = false;
        user.LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        class1Object.Users.Update(user);
        var updatedRecords = await class1Object.SaveChangesAsync();
        await class1Object.AddUpdateUserAgencyReports(agencyId);
        return updatedRecords;
    }
```

In the above method,

_provider is of type IServiceProvider interface
scope is of IServiceScope type
class1Object is of type Class1

How do I mock the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` method?  I have written the below setup and the unit test but, I am getting the following error:

```
private Class2 Class2Setup(User user)
        {
            dbSetUserList.Add(user);
            dbSetAgencyList.Add(agency);
            
            _mockServiceScope.Setup(d => d.ServiceProvider).Returns(_mockServiceProvider.Object);
            _mockServiceScopeFactory.Setup(d => d.CreateScope()).Returns(_mockServiceScope.Object);
            _mockServiceProvider.Setup(d => d.GetService(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory)))
                .Returns(_mockServiceScopeFactory.Object);
            
            _mockServiceProvider.Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(Class1))).Returns(_mockClass1Object.Object);

            var dbSetUser = dbSetUserList.AsQueryable();
            _mockDbSetUser.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(dbSetUser.Provider);
            _mockDbSetUser.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(dbSetUser.Expression);
            _mockDbSetUser.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(dbSetUser.ElementType);
            _mockDbSetUser.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(dbSetUser.GetEnumerator());
            
            var dbSetAgency = dbSetAgencyList.AsQueryable();
            _mockDbSetAgency.As<IQueryable<Agency>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(dbSetAgency.Provider);
            _mockDbSetAgency.As<IQueryable<Agency>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(dbSetAgency.Expression);
            _mockDbSetAgency.As<IQueryable<Agency>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(dbSetAgency.ElementType);
            _mockDbSetAgency.As<IQueryable<Agency>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(dbSetAgency.GetEnumerator());

            
            _mockClass1Object.Setup(d => d.Users).Returns(() => _mockDbSetUser.Object);
            _mockClass1Object.Setup(d => d.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User,bool>>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(user);
            _mockClass1Object.Setup(d => d.Users.Update(user));
            _mockClass1Object.Setup(d => d.Agencies).Returns(new Func<DbSet<Agency>>(() => _mockDbSetAgency.Object));

            var reportingUserDataAccess = new ReportingUserDataAccess(_mockServiceProvider.Object);
            return reportingUserDataAccess;
            
        }


    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var result = _reportingUserDataAccess2.Method1(user.AgencyId, user.UserId);
        
    }
```

Error:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... => ....FirstOrDefaultAsync<User>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
xtension methods (here: EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
   at Moq.Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method, Expression expression) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Guard.cs:line 97
   at Moq.InvocationShape..ctor(LambdaExpression expression, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, Boolean exactGenericTypeArguments, Boolean skipMatcherInitialization, Boolean allowNonOverridable) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\InvocationShape.cs:line 85
   at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.<Split>g__Split|5_0(Expression e, Expression& r, InvocationShape& p, Boolean assignment, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 235
   at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 150
   at Moq.Mock.SetupRecursive[TSetup](Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Func`4 setupLast, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 601
   at Moq.Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 505
   at Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock`1.cs:line 454
```

The error is coming on line :  `_mockClass1Object.Setup(d => d.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User,bool>>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(user);` in the setup method.

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what are `Class1` and `Users` ? You can't mock every method in `IQueryable` nor do you have to. Any `List<T>` or `T[]` can be used as an `IQueryable`. On the other hand, if you try to mock a DbContext<T>, you're doing it wrong. DbContext already supports unit testing through the in-memory provider, which  is a bit better than any mock or `List<T>`.

Comment: Mocking is used when it's too hard to create dummy test objects. It's not meant to be used everywhere. Besides, when your mock requires so much configuration you're probably mocking at the wrong abstraction level or using the wrong abstractions altogether. In such cases you end up testing your mocking code, not the code you wanted to test in the first place

Answer (score 0):

It's an extension method, you can't mock it. Under the covers it'll probably invoke the underlying source (Users) query provider ExecuteAsync method, that's what you need to mock on your db sets.

Word of advice: what you're doing is really hard, use a real database or, because it's an async method and not supported by the in-memory provider, a library that does it (my library [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) may suit your needs).

Comment: Why use a third party library instead of the in-memory provider? What does that library do and why is it better than the built-in unit testing support?

Comment: Async methods don't work with the in-memory provider